# My Ionic 5 app release version not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native, ionic5

I built my an app with Ionic 5, The app is makes requests to an API which I made with Laravel 8, data is sent in json form while an API key is required and  it is sent in the headers section.

Everything works fine when the App is built in debug version however the release version does not even give an indication of what's happening. For example the login button when pressed it does not do anything it only gives a timeout message which I had set in the app to let the user know the process failed.
The debug app works perfectly without any issues but the release app does not.
I'm sorry I can't post the entire code here since I can't pinpoint where the error seems to be coming from and it's a lot of code.

App - Ionic 5, Angular.
API - Laravel 8
Requests in JSON
Headers - API Key

I later checked the app logs on Android Studio logcat and this is the error that kept popping up:  "E/chromium: [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(981)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202"

Comment: use https (not http) for http services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your server start with `https` and have a valid `SSL certificate`.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. The certificate turned out to be self signed, I went for Comodo ssl and it was solved